# Cannot Find JumpListItemBackgroundConverter in C# from XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, findname

I want to dynamically change the colour of my Jump List of my longlistselector. I have the JumpListBackgroundCOnverter defined in the xaml as below in the resources

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Name="BackgroundConvert" x:Key="BackgroundConverter" Enabled="#FFA20025"/>
```

In C# after the components are initialized BackgroundConvert returns null

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackgroundConvert.Enabled = new SolidColorBrush(ThemeGradient.Color);
```

I change the enabled value to a new brush, and plan to change it throughout the code. For some reason it returns null and crashes.

In InitializeComponent I suppose FindName returns null but I cannot figure out why

```
     this.BackgroundConvert = ((Microsoft.Phone.Controls.JumpListItemBackgroundConverter)(this.FindName("BackgroundConvert")));
```

Btw, this is for windows phone 8!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use x:key in resources , You don't need to use x:Name="BackgroundConvert".

```
<phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter" Enabled="#FFA20025"/>
```

Then you can access it from Resources using it's `x:Key="BackgroundConverter"`  value in your code behind. Resources is a Dictionary.

```
var converter = (Microsoft.Phone.Controls.JumpListItemBackgroundConverter)this.Resources["BackgroundConverter"];
```